# Python pickle weird behavior on using different file modes for the file where pickled object is stored

Tags: python, pickle

I am pickling a dictionary with the following statement:

```
pickle.dump(paramsToSave, open('testvars.txt','wb'))
```

I am unpickling with the following:

```
vars = pickle.load(open('testvars.txt','rb'))
```

Now when I use file mode 'w' in pickling and 'r' in unpickling, it is fine. Same for wb-rb, wb-r combinations.

But when I use w-rb combination, I get an error:

```
ValueError: insecure string pickle
```

Can someone please explain this behavior? And which is the right file mode combination to use?

Edit: I am using Python 2.6.6 on Windows 7

Comment: Presumably you are on Windows or another platform with a standard line separator convention other than `\n`.

Comment: What Python version are you using? Python 3 switched the default protocol being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should *always* use binary mode for pickle files. On platforms where this matters (e.g. Windows), opening a file in text mode means that all line terminators are translated; `\n` becomes `\r\n` on write, and `\r\n` becomes `\n` again on reading.

On Python 2 the default pickle protocol is ASCII-based, but that doesn't mean that the contents of the values are not going to be affected. For your `w` -> `rb` example, most likely a value with a `\n` embedded was written out as `\r\n`, then read as `\r\n` meaning the *length* of the data changed, triggering the error message because certain quoting expectations were not met (the closing quote was not read because the string length changed).

The fact that you didn't run into this specific exception with the other non-binary combinations does not mean you didn't have problems anyway. Values could still end up being corrupted.

All other protocol versions are binary based, meaning you can break the protocol in more creative ways still.